# Math mode inside a table

Tags: tables, math-mode, equations, split

I'm trying to put an equation inside a table. But every time I try, i will receive an error. I have about 10 equations of this kind:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
R_{1.0}=  \bigl\{& \pair{\text{256},\{2\}},\pair{128,\{1\}},\pair{64,\  {2\}\}}, \\ &
\pair{32,\{1\}\}}, \pair{8,\{2\}}, \pair{4,\{5\}}, \pair{2,\{1\}}\bigr\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

I want put all of them in the same table, any suggestion?

Edit:
This is the code for \pair:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pair}{\langle}{\rangle}
```

Comment: What error do you get? How is `\pair` defined? It would be ideal if you could post what we call a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your issue. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add the code of a complete document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that shows the error.  So far I can only see that in `\pair{64,\  {2\}\}}` there are spurious spaces between `\ `and `{` which probably shouldn't be there. After removing them and adding a definition for `\pair`, your code compiles.

Comment: Sorry, i will upload the rest of the code. Anyway, the problem is not on the equation, that is fine, but on putting this equation on a table.

Comment: In this case your posting doesn't tell us anything about your problem since it is completely unclear what you mean by *putting this equation on a table*.

Comment: If you always use a `\{..\}` in the second place of the pair, I suggest you `\newcommand*\pair[1]{\angles{\dopair#1\relax}} \def\dopair#1,#2\relax{#1,\{#2\}} \DeclarePairedDelimiter\angles{\langle}{\rangle}`. Then use `\pair{256,2}, \pair{128,1}, \pair{64,2}, ..., \pair{4,5}`. I think it's easier to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to insert a *display* equation inside a `tabular`, then you need to use a fixed-width `p`-column, since the equation is centered within this width horizontally.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pairdel}{\langle}{\rangle}
\newcommand{\pair}[1]{\paired#1\delimtoken}
\def\paired#1,#2\delimtoken{\pairdel{#1,\{#2\}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
    R_{1.0} = \bigl\{ & \pair{256, 2}, \pair{128, 1}, \pair{64, 2}, \\
                      & \pair{32, 1}, \pair{8, 2}, \pair{4, 5}, \pair{2, 1}\bigr\}
  \end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{.7\linewidth} | }
  {\begin{equation*}
    \begin{split}
      R_{1.0} = \bigl\{ & \pair{256, 2}, \pair{128, 1}, \pair{64, 2}, \\
                        & \pair{32, 1}, \pair{8, 2}, \pair{4, 5}, \pair{2, 1}\bigr\}
    \end{split}
  \end{equation*}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note how the equation is placed inside a group in order to hide certain `tabular`-like content (like `\\` and `&`).

I've also replaced your `\pair` macro with something that provides you with consistency across its usage: `\pair{a,b}` > `<a,{b}>`.

Comment: Ok thanks for you answer... anyway i have big spacing between an equation and another equation inside the table. I used     \setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt} \setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}

If I want reduce more the space between an equation and another how can I do?

Comment: @Sharknado: Don't use successive `equation` environments. Instead, put them together into a single display using something like `aligned` (mentioned in [the other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353878/5764)).

Answer (score 5):

The right tool is `aligned`, in this case: you don't want display math mode that only makes sense in paragraph mode, not in table cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,booktabs}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\pair}{\langle}{\rangle}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
An equation &
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
  R_{1.0} = \bigl\{ & \pair{256, \{2\}}, \pair{128, \{1\}}, \pair{64, \{2\}}, \\
                    & \pair{32, \{1\}}, \pair{8, \{2\}}, \pair{4, \{5\}}, \pair{2, \{1\}}\bigr\}
  \end{aligned}$
\\
Another equation & $a+b=c$
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]